# Convert ASP.NET code to Classic ASP code

Tags: asp.net, dll, asp-classic, push-notification, mpns

I have developed the application(Server App) in ASP.NET which is used to send the Push Notification to the Windows Phone(Client App).But I'm giving this application to my client, He is using Classic ASP and he can't able to implement the server code in Classic ASP.
So is there any way to `Convert ASP.NET code to Classic ASP code` or can I able to make the ASP.NET code .dll and implement it into Classic ASP ?
Thanks.

Comment: I have to ask, here - **Why**?  Why not just compile the code and your client can install the working version. This keeps the code in your hands and stops the client from messing it up.

Comment: My client have another mobile apps, for these apps he is using the server-side app in Classic ASP, and he wants to implement the push notification service in the same server-side app, That's why.

Comment: Such pushes and pulls shouldn't matter. If the client decides to issue a command to your app it should be able to deal with it, and vice versa. If you hand your code over you may lose future contracts because he can simply rip your code off and do it himself. (But I agree with Kumar Manish below in this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET is not an updated version of classic ASP,so there is  only option to  re-writing the code in classic asp. There are no "converters" that would do that.

There is another option , you can intergation asp.net application to classic ASP.

Comment: by integrating you can think of let your ASP.Net code expose an (http) API that can be used by classic ASP.